# How to send data from an activity to servicce

Tags: android, service, android-intent

I am trying to send data from an activity to service via intents.

This is the code in my activity class

```
Intent i= new Intent(this,SampService.class);

    i.putExtra("startTimeHour", timePicker1.getCurrentHour());
    i.putExtra("endTimeHour", timePicker2.getCurrentHour());
    i.putExtra("startTimeMinute",timePicker1.getCurrentMinute());
    i.putExtra("endTimeMinute", timePicker2.getCurrentMinute());
    startActivity(i);
```

This is the code in my service class

```
public class SampService extends Service implements Runnable {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
public void onCreate()
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String startTimeHour,startTimeMinute,endTimeHour,endTimeMinute;



}
public void onStart()
{
    Thread t=new Thread(this);
    t.start();
}
public void run() {



}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SampleService is a Service, you should use   `startService(i);` instead of   `startActivity(i);` The data attached to the intent can then be retrieved in the Service.

Answer (score 2):

You don't send data from an Activity to a Service with Intents. The Activity needs to bind to the service and then you call methods on the binder. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Another option would be to have your Activity send a broadcast Intent with the data and your service could set up a BroadcastReceiver to listen for that.

What are you trying to use the service for? Maybe there is an easier or lighter-weight solution to your problem.

Comment: "You don't send data from an Activity to a Service with Intents." -- yes, you do. It's the command pattern, using `startService()` to send commands in the form of `Intents`. Quoting [the documenation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html) "Multiple requests to start the service result in multiple corresponding calls to the service's onStartCommand(). However, only one request to stop the service (with stopSelf() or stopService()) is required to stop it." This works nicely with `IntentServices`.

Comment: @David Wassler i am using service to check the time values and turn silent mode on between my start and end time

Comment: OK, then you need the service to be running even when your Activity isn't. The solution from @Akhil should work. [This question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252371/unable-to-get-data-from-activity-to-service) shows how to pass values in the Intent used in `startService()` and how to retrieve them in `onStartCommand()` in the service.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yep, I stand corrected. What I meant was that you don't do it using `startActivity()`. But obviously I didn't get that out quite right. I could edit the answer to point that out, but I think that is moot at this point.